# Custom In-App advertisements

Tags: ios, ads, appstore-approval

I have been scouring the Apple App Store guidelines but haven't found an answer to this question. Are custom in-app advertisements permissible? What I mean is that I am populating ads in my app myself from my own database. Also these ads link to an external website so this might be an issue as well, but again I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you think Apple would care about where your ads come from?

Comment: They seem to have pretty specific guidelines. I wasn't sure if all advertisements were required to be handled through iAd or not.

Comment: People have been using other forms of ads long before iAd even existed. Besides, iAd is going away soon.

Comment: OK, cool. Thanks for the info!

Comment: look into admob, https://www.google.com/admob/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)